# Как регистрировать несколько экземпляров класса в DryIoC?

Tags: c#

Использую DryIoC без Prism. Подскажите как регистрировать и затем резолвить несколько экземпляров класса с параметризованным конструктором без обязательного использования serviceKey? Сейчас я это делаю таким образом:

Имеется класс:

```
class MyClass: IMyInterface
{
   public MyClass(MyItem item, ILogger<MyClass> logger = null)
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

Регистрация:

```
var container = new Container();
...
var id = 0;
foreach (var item in Items)
{
    container.RegisterInstance<IMyInterface>(
        new MyClass(item,
        container.Resolve<ILogger<MyClass>>()),
        IfAlreadyRegistered.AppendNewImplementation,
        serviceKey: id++);
}
```

Резолвлю так:

```
var MyInstances = App.Container.ResolveMany<IMyInterface>(behavior: ResolveManyBehavior.AsFixedArray);
```

Все работает, но если удалить serviceKey, в MyInstances будет только один элемент. Вероятно таков механизм работы RegisterInstance, и здесь я пользуюсь им не по прямому назначению. Поэтому есть ощущение, что это плохой способ зарегистрировать несколько экземпляров. А существует ли в DryIoC более правильный вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя разные ключи, то не нужно добавлять `IfAlreadyRegistered.AppendNewImplementation,`.
Во-первых, у Вас у всегда одна реализация, а именно `MyClass` - а значит только первая регистрация сработает, а остальные будут отброшены.
Во-вторых, эта опция действуют только когда `serviceKey` не задан.

Еще скорее всего, не нужно в цикле делать `container.Resolve<ILogger<MyClass>>()`, чтобы получить один и тот же logger.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я пока пытаюсь понять, это то что я хотел или нет....

Comment: Вы пишете  _Еще скорее всего, не нужно в цикле делать container.Resolve<ILogger<MyClass>>(), чтобы получить один и тот же logger._       Не вполне понял, что Вы имеете ввиду.  Мне нужно создать несколько экземпляров MyClass - и их количество должно быть равно количеству Items, и соответственно в конструктор должен отправляться соответствующий уже заранее созданный экземпляр Item. А логгер  я так понимаю там без разницы все равно будет один и тот же.

Comment: Раз логгер один - то и резолвить его можно один раз и везде передавать этот объект. Вызов Resolve в цикле - это не бесплатная и ненужная здесь операция.

Comment: Согласен, это будет более удачно.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо - Ваш ответ помог мне разобраться в моей ошибке. Я на всякий случай отписался ниже как именно я теперь это делаю. Немножко  видимо запутался из-за имени элемента перечисления - AppendNewImplementation. Фактически оно позволяет регистрировать не просто newImplementation, а скорее onlyNewImplementation.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать просто RegisterInstance без дополнительных аргументов. То есть:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IMyInterface>(
    new MyClass(item,
    container.Resolve<ILogger<MyClass>>()));
```

Моя ошибка была в том, что я попытался использовать противоречащие друг другу по смыслу аргументы. Если я все верно понял, при использовании `IfAlreadyRegistered.AppendNewImplementation` будет регистрироваться не новый экземпляр, а именно новая реализация. Если вдобавок к этому указать уникальный serviceKey, то регистрация все же будет производиться каждый раз. Если же требуется каждый раз добавлять новую регистрацию для каждого экземпляра можно указать `IfAlreadyRegistered.AppendNotKeyed`, но это глупо и не обязательно, т.к. это значение используется по умолчанию.